# How can I calculate a field based on fields in other tables while inserting a record (in a procedure)

Tags: plsql

I'm sorry for the confusing title, but couldn't find another way to ask it.

Let's say I want to write a procedure `add_salesline`. I enter all the fields with parameters, except `subtotal`. Subtotal (just the price for the salesline) needs to be calculated based on fields in other tables such as `productprice` in the table `products`, `pricereduction` in the table `promotion`, etc. (based on the  properties).

How can I do this? I've been trying to solve this problem for a good week now, and it's just not working...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably one of the parameters passed to procedure `add_salesline()` is `productid`, or whatever. So you use that to SELECT `products.productprice`, `promotion.pricereduction` and whatever else you need to perform the calculation.

The purpose of writing a stored procedure is to associate several calls into a single program unit. So `add_salesline()` might look something like this (lots of caveats because your question is very light on details):

```
create or replace procedure add_salesline(
  p_orderno in salesline.orderno%type
  , p_salesqty in salesline.salesqty%type
  , p_productid in products.productid%type
)
is
    new_rec salesline%rowtype;
begin
    new_rec.orderno := p_orderno;
    new_rec.salesqty := p_salesqty;
    new_rec.productid := p_productid;

    select p_salesqty * (p.productprice * nvl(pp.pricereduction, 1))
    into new_rec.subtotal 
    from products p
        left outer join promotion pp
        on pp.productid = p.productid
    where p.productid = p_productid
    ;

    insert into salesline
    value new_rec;

end;
```

This code assumes `pricereduction` is a rate. If the value is an absolute discount the formula will be different `(p.productprice - nvl(pp.pricereduction, 0))`. Or if it's a replacement price: `coalesce(pp.pricereduction, p.productprice)`.

Comment: Thanks, that did help. I'm sorry for the question not being clear, I was really tired when I wrote it.